# cordova: How to debug app remotely?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, remote-debugging

My client located on a remote distance and having an issue with my app. I want to debug this app remotely in his phone.

Is this really possible?
If so then how can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways, each with varying degrees of success:

1. To see the actual problem the app is having, your client can download "AirServer", it's a way to mirror the iPhone to their computer screen. You can then use any screensharing software (like Google Hangouts or Skype) to see what's going on.
2. Release an update that includes a "Logging Service" that logs to localStorage for when you have an error; and then enable access to that through a special sequence on the phone (if you aren't worried about people seeing it, you can make it a menu option. If you are, then hide it via speciifc touch presses).  You can then dump any and all errors to that screen and load it that way.  I used this approach when creating [the Bluetooth Low Energy Demo app](https://github.com/Jewelbots/ble-demo-app/blob/master/app/scripts/app.js).

Answer (score 2):

As the apk is unavailable, the only possibility is you can share your client's screen and use chrome debugging tools.